# How dangerous is it to set up public key access from a remote bash script?

Tags: bash, security, ssh, ssh-keygen

I have a network of a few dozen devices (mostly Linux) and I want to secure my network with public keys. I thought it would be useful for consistency and speed to create a USB drive with a bash script utility to take 
a) remote host IP / hostname
b) remote username (plaintext)
c) remote password (plaintext)
d) choose from connect 'this to that', 'that to this' or 'both directions'
Then, as needed create the `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048` locally and/or remotely, and appending the public key from the source into the target /.ssh/authorized-keys file

I'd also plan to store the hostname/IP, public and private keys, username & password (I have physical access and want to keep a record for access).

No doubt this could be quicker to do manually for the number of devices I have but nevertheless, it's interesting to know if this is a viable approach?

**Providing this is used as an occasional script, run from an otherwise disconnected USB, what dangers would I face and what mitigations should I take?**

Ultimately, I'd like a utility that can set up keys, revoke password access, choose DHCP/static + configure static and set hostnames and record it all in JSON, so I can use a d3 directed graph representation of my network topology with popup help for the credentials for each node & link. All on an encrypted USB drive!

Comment: Sorry if this requires a discursive answer, but I hoped there might be enough specific answers to be of general interest/use :)

Comment: Do you trust the systems you plug the USB key into? They can copy your private key. You might prefer an encryption token device like an [OpenPGP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenPGP_card) card or [YubiKey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YubiKey). I think this question is better suited for [Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @greg : If possible, restore the Q you deleted today. I' won't be able to spend time immediately, but I'll work to help you understand how to boil down your problem to the basics, and find a resolution. (If you can't restore, repost. In either case, reply here by a comment that you have done so). Good luck.

Comment: @shelter I restored the question and added a comment trying to reframe the question in the abstract. I'm not going to be able to follow up for a bit as I'm going on holiday. Thanks for getting back to me and being encouraging :)

Comment: Have a good vacation. I have been busy and didn't get to look at your revision yet. It's late for me now, so won't go looking for it until at least tomorrow. If I haven't looked at it by the time you get back, be sure to ping me. I may also have to ask clarifying Qs. Note that my ID is spelled with 2 L's ;-) .Have fun.